# Merge multiple raster .tif in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: raster, merge, qgis-3

I'm trying to merge 12 .tif raster layers (raster -> misc -> build virtual raster), but keep getting this error:

> Loading resulting layers The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>
> - /var/folders/4f/3vtn5c5s7zd3qnrn03_5bc1r0000gn/T/processing_201ee1195d8f460f8c74a248f1bab91c/878b8a3be722499da52c93b6f72c083c/OUTPUT.vrt
>
> You
>   can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
>   information about the execution of the algorithm."
>
> "2018-10-19T13:21:01     INFO    gdalbuildvrt -resolution average
>   -separate -r nearest -input_file_list /var/folders/4f/3vtn5c5s7zd3qnrn03_5bc1r0000gn/T/processing_201ee1195d8f460f8c74a248f1bab91c/buildvrtInputFiles.txt
>   /var/folders/4f/3vtn5c5s7zd3qnrn03_5bc1r0000gn/T/processing_201ee1195d8f460f8c74a248f1bab91c/523821c6a9a64cd2a7789f266b312785/OUTPUT.vrt
>   2018-10-19T13:21:01     INFO    GDAL execution console output
>                /bin/sh: gdalbuildvrt: command not found

Comment: There is something wrong with your installation because "gdalbuildvrt: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

Are you running windows or...?

My experience in windows is that uninstalling QGIS and reinstalling QGIS (along with GDAL) as part of the OSGEO4W installer is the easiest way to get an installation that works.

Alternatively you could try to reinstall GDAL.

I have just tested (raster -> misc -> build virtual raster) and it works well with this approach to installation.

Comment: I have a macbook pro :/